# collect the int and print them each on a new line according to their string

Tags: c#, dictionary, sum

I am here to ask how to read one string line, check if it is contained in a Dictionary and if so, add a number to it. For example if the input is **Gold** and the next line is **115**: the number should be assigned to the string. Each time the loop rotates it should check if the **string** is contained and add the next **int** line to it.

```
var text = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

while (true)
{               

    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
    {
        string[] sequenceOfStrings = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split();

        var material = sequenceOfStrings[0];

        if (material == "stop")
        {
            break;
        }
        if (!text.ContainsKey(material))
        {
            text.Add(material, i);
        }
```

You are given a sequence of strings, each on a new line. Every *odd line* on the console is representing a resource (e.g. **Gold, Silver, Copper, and so on**), and *every even* – quantity. Your task is to **collect the resources and print them each on a new line.** Print the resources and their quantities in format:
{resource} –> {quantity}. The quantities inputs will be in the range **[1 … 2 000 000 000]**

Thank you for the patience.
Tom

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The code you've written so far has some correct parts and some incorrect parts. Try not to write everything in one go, do it in steps and test your code each time.

Comment: @Stijn Havent we played league a long time ago? lol 
Ive tried that, but i cannot find a way on how to read each one from every line and add them to a specific "resourse". Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Unlikely, I think I tried out the game for a few hours, a long time ago. Maybe we played WoW together at some point. And meanwhile it looks like someone else has answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

The code that solves your issue could look like this:

```
        var text = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

        while (true)
        {
            string material = Console.ReadLine();
            if(material == "stop")
            {
                break;
            }


            string quantityString = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!Int32.TryParse(quantityString, out int newQuantity))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (text.TryGetValue(material, out int currentQuantity))
            {
                text[material] = currentQuantity + newQuantity;
            }
            else
            {
                text[material] = newQuantity;
            }
        }

        foreach(var item in text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Value};");
        }
```

BTW, do you really need SortedDictionary here? If you have a lot of keys then ( depending on input data distribution ) it could take a bit more time to do *TryGetValue* than for ordinary Dictionary.